# Как найти нужные мне строки по условию?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Хочу вывести из таблицы строки, где в значении есть `_Р_`. По итогу получается очень неточная выборка с лишними данными.

Пример самого значения из таблицы: `TEST - [КОД-12_Р_КЖ1.2_S1_W22.2_R21_В_name.E]`

Код, который я пишу:

```
 SELECT * FROM table where "title" like '%_Р_%'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Символы `_` в [`LIKE`](https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/like.php) - маска для одного любого символа, поэтому ваше выражение эквивалентно '%Р%'. Нужно экранировать подчеркивания обратным слешем:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 where "title" like '%\_Р\_%'
```

[Демо](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/929f5/1)